# df.at updating multiple indexes on DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = {'col1': [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5)],
        'col2': [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


lista = []
df['test'] = None
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    lista.append([random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5)])
    df.at[index, 'test'] = lista
    print(index,lista)

display(df)
```

Why the final output shows the last iterated list always? I mean, since `df.at` updates a value at an index and my index is serial (using iterrows) why the output is `[[first list], [second list], [third list], [fourth list], [fifth list]]` in all rows?

My desired output is:

```
test
[[first list]]
[[first list], [second list]]
[[first list], [second list], [third list]]
[[first list], [second list], [third list], [fourth list]]
[[first list], [second list], [third list], [fourth list], [fifth list]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the undesired result because you're updating the same list `lista` in every iteration. Instead, assign a copy of the list to a dataframe:

```py
import random

import pandas as pd

data = {
    "col1": [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5)],
    "col2": [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5)],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


lista = []
df["test"] = None
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    lista.append([random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5)])
    df.at[index, "test"] = lista.copy()       # <-- copy a list here!
    print(index, lista)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2                                                                                                           test
0    90    55                                                                                         [[47, 70, 98, 43, 95]]
1    74    16                                                                    [[47, 70, 98, 43, 95], [4, 86, 69, 84, 51]]
2    45    90                                             [[47, 70, 98, 43, 95], [4, 86, 69, 84, 51], [81, 74, 33, 100, 77]]
3    77    56                        [[47, 70, 98, 43, 95], [4, 86, 69, 84, 51], [81, 74, 33, 100, 77], [34, 47, 85, 4, 74]]
4    49    43  [[47, 70, 98, 43, 95], [4, 86, 69, 84, 51], [81, 74, 33, 100, 77], [34, 47, 85, 4, 74], [70, 29, 25, 47, 99]]
```